# Оптимизация и улучшение js barcode detector

Tags: javascript, камера, barcode

Заказчик просит интегрировать в его продукт новый сканер для датамаириксов. Выбор пал на этот ресурс https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode.

В этой библиотеке были сделаны доработки (чтение инвертированных кодов, увеличение картинки чтобы читать маленькие коды как на пачке сигарет, поставили серый фильтр на `canvas`, чтобы как-то приблизить к черно белому эти коды).

Но на некоторой партии товара, на пачках, код стал более расплывчатый и соответственно при увеличении картинки в `canvas`, код становится почти нечитаемым.

Можно ли как-то улучшить качество картинки при увеличении или как то обвести в `canvas` данные коды, чтобы они были четкими. Или может переделать растровую картинку в векторную. Может есть у кого идеи куда почитать?

Comment: *"можно ли как то улучшить качество картинки"* - это невозможно. А вот "переделать растровую картинку в векторную" можно без проблем, только качества это все равно не прибавит. Если разрешение картинки ниже какого-то порогового значения, недостаточного для уверенного распознавания, то никакими хитрыми манипуляциями ситуацию уже не исправить.

Comment: пинать не буду, вопрос улучшил

Comment: Спасибо большое !